# Understanding precedence in Symfony2 chain of imports

Tags: symfony

let's say that you have the three following symfony2 config files (extremely simplified), where the file loaded by AppKernel as the current environment is the first one, app/config/config_env.yml:

app/config/config_env.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config2.yml }
    - { resource: config3.yml }
parameters:
    param: one
```

app/config/config2.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config4.yml }
parameters:
    param: two
```

app/config/config3.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config5.yml }
parameters:
    param: three
```

app/config/config4.yml:

```
parameters:
    param: four
```

app/config/config5.yml:

```
parameters:
    param: five
```

Whenever I refer to param from my code, can you help me understand what is the value associated with param (one, two, three, four or five), and why? Or, in other words, what are Symfony2 precedence rules regarding imports?

Thanks,

Rodrigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think about what symfony is doing.

First of all, it loads the config_env.yml.

```
imports:
    - { resource: config2.yml }
    - { resource: config3.yml }
parameters:
    param: one
```

Next step: Load the imports.

```
imports:
    - { resource: config4.yml }
parameters:
    param: two
imports:
    - { resource: config5.yml }
parameters:
    param: three
parameters:
    param: one
```

Next step: combine them

```
imports:
    - { resource: config4.yml }
    - { resource: config5.yml }
parameters:
    param: two
    param: three
    param: one
```

Next step: Load the imports

```
parameters:
    param: four
parameters:
    param: five
parameters:
    param: two
    param: three
    param: one
```

Next step: combine them

```
parameters:
    param: four
    param: five
    param: two
    param: three
    param: one
```

Now it's important to know that symfony overrides set parameters.
So what's the answer? At the end param is one. Try it.